# How often should the bridges list that is downloaded be replaced?

Tags: security

Are they changed, and is there a recommended time to change them?

Answer (score 0):

if it works - there's no need to explicitly rotate them. It is recommended to add new ones - but for "just in case" reason. I haven't monitored the bridge list changes frequency, but in 2 years after a request I've received a different bridges via email request